# Selection field with widget="radio" not getting required effect applied with attrs in XML file in Odoo 12

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am trying to make a **selection field** with *widget="radio"* required using *attrs in an XML file*. The selection field doesn't get required with widget="radio" applied to it. but When I remove the radio widget, the selection field gets the required effect in form view upon creating new records.

This is the selection field where I appied required there:

```
<field name="installments_calculation" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}" attrs="{'required': [('repayment_method', '=', 'salary deduction')]}"/>
```

And this is my repayment_method:

```
repayment_method = fields.Selection([('cash/bank', 'Cash/Bank'), ('salary deduction', 'Salary Deduction')])
```

I want the selection field gets required with applying the required attribute upon a condition in the XML file. Is this behavior is normal with selection fields with widget="radio" or I have done something wrong? If this is normal, how can I get the selection field required with widget="radio"?

Comment: Interesting question! What do you mean by "required effect"? Do you just mean there is no hint whatsoever in the client or does Odoo just don't warn the user when not setting anything with the widget? Latter one should be opened as Issue at [https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues)

Comment: In my case, there is no hint for the client in form view and also Odoo doesn't warn the user when the user doesn't select any one of the selections of radio buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work normally but if this problem is with the widget report a `issue` in Odoo Github :

For now just use `api.constrains` to get the same behavior

```py
 # remember to depend on both fields
 @api.constrains('installments_calculation','repayment_method')
 def check_installments_calculation(self):
    for rec in self:
        if not rec.installments_calculation and rec.repayment_method == 'salary deduction':
            raise exception.ValidationError(_('You message here'))
```

Comment: What if I override **def create()** and **def write()**  of the model for checking if the installments_calculation field is filled with data or not?

Comment: It work just like constrains but you will write the code two times, and will deal with dictionary, in write method you have to check if the one of the field has changed. to much work and using api.constrains is easier to write and clear for you team work for this cases

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a fix for the client side which is the approach that I was looking for:

```
odoo.define('mymodule.web.radio.required', function(require){
  var relational_fields = require('web.relational_fields');

  relational_fields.FieldRadio.include({
      isSet: function () {
          return (this.mode === 'edit')? ($(this.$el).find("[checked='true']")).length > 0: this.value;
      },
  });
});
```